# Type mismatch on value class with value field and imported cats either syntax

Tags: scala, implicit, scala-cats, scala-macros

I use value classes from [scala-newtype](https://github.com/estatico/scala-newtype) library but they doesn't look compatible with old (version **1.4.0**) [cats-core](https://github.com/typelevel/cats) library. Look at the example:

```scala
import io.estatico.newtype.macros.newtype
import SomeClass.Foo
import cats.syntax.either._

class SomeClass {
  
  def takeFoo(foo: Foo): Unit = {
    val strValue: String = foo.value // here I have compile error
    println(strValue)
  }
}

object SomeClass {
  @newtype case class Foo(value: String)
}

object Application extends App {
  new SomeClass().takeFoo(Foo("x"))
}
```

this code doesn't compile with error:

```sh
type mismatch;
 found   : SomeClass.Foo
    (which expands to)  SomeClass.Foo.Type
 required: String
```

[scastie example here](https://scastie.scala-lang.org/HgdgUJWxT3CsiqXjrnI3MA)

build settings:

```scala
addCompilerPlugin("org.scalamacros" % "paradise" % "2.1.1" cross CrossVersion.full)
```

dependencies:

```scala
scalaVersion := "2.12.10"
libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
  "io.estatico" %% "newtype" % "0.4.4",
  "org.typelevel" %% "cats-core" % "1.4.0"
)
```

I found that old `cats-core` has class `EitherIdOpsBinCompat0`:

```scala
final class EitherIdOpsBinCompat0[A](val value: A) extends AnyVal {
  def leftNec[B]: Either[NonEmptyChain[A], B] = Left(NonEmptyChain.one(value))
  def rightNec[B]: Either[NonEmptyChain[B], A] = Right(value)
}
```

which has field `value` of type `A` and if I replace the `strValue` definition by:

```scala
val strValue: String = catsSyntaxEitherIdBinCompat0(foo).value
```

I see the same error.

So, the **main question**: Why compiler doesn't see the value class field `value` but trying to make implicit conversion into `EitherIdOpsBinCompat0` from `cats.syntax.either`? (see `catsSyntaxEitherIdBinCompat0` function)

```scala
private[syntax] trait EitherSyntaxBinCompat0 {
  implicit final def catsSyntaxEitherBinCompat0[A, B](eab: Either[A, B]): EitherOpsBinCompat0[A, B] =
    new EitherOpsBinCompat0(eab)

  implicit final def catsSyntaxEitherIdBinCompat0[A](a: A): EitherIdOpsBinCompat0[A] =
    new EitherIdOpsBinCompat0(a)
}
```

And how I can avoid this behavior?

---

PS:

in new `cats-core` versions, `value` field from `EitherIdOpsBinCompat0` has `private` modificator and where is no problems with calling `value` field of value class.

```scala
final private[syntax] class EitherIdOpsBinCompat0[A](private val value: A) extends AnyVal { ... }
```

Comment: This is probably more a question about `newtype` than about cats.

Answer (score 2):

Based on the documentation of [scala-newtype](https://github.com/estatico/scala-newtype) which you linked to, your newtype `SomeClass.Foo` translates to — more or less — the following code after macro expansion:

```scala
object SomeClass {
  type Foo = Foo.Type
  object Foo {
    type Repr = String
    type Base = Any { type Foo$newtype }
    trait Tag extends Any
    type Type <: Base with Tag

    def apply(x: String): Foo = x.asInstanceOf[Foo]

    implicit final class Ops$newtype(val $this$: Type) extends AnyVal {
      def value: String = $this$.asInstanceOf[String]
    }
  }
}
```

As you can see `value` is actually an extension method added by an implicit class. Just like the accidental extension method `value` in `EitherIdOpsBinCompat0`. So the compiler either has to prefer one of those extension methods over the other or fail compilation. I'm pretty sure there's a rule that says that imported implicits (`import cats.syntax.either._`) are preferred in this case.

Comment: You are right. Interesting fact: after adding `import SomeClass.Foo._` everything compiles despite on either syntax import. But, if I add another value class `Bar` with the same field `value`, it fails again with the same error. Seems it would be good to clarify why the compiler chooses `implicit` from either syntax. Maybe because it's more general but I'm not sure. Updated example:
https://scastie.scala-lang.org/AySmUs8tQM2UP2X5vV0HDA